# Stop at breakpoints only in certain thread

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging

I have some multithreaded code and am trying to set up some breakpoints in Eclipse so I can do some debugging.

The breakpoint I want to set is in a class used by all of the threads. However, I only want the breakpoint to be hit when I am in the main thread. Is there a way to do this in Eclipse?

I have tried to use the 'conditional' breakpoint options but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Conditional breakpoints are the way to go. Why didn't they work?

Comment: I think my problem was with the expression I was trying. I was using, `Thread.currentThread().getId() == 0` for the main, when I think I should have been doing `getId() == 1`.  I like the answers so far that suggest 'name' as those are easier viewed in the debugger.

Comment: Yeah, using the name is better in this regard, especially since you can set it yourself in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conditional breakpoint approach is good. The condition should looks like: `Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("main")`.

If you want to set up a breakpoint for another thread you just have to change `"main"` to a thread-specific name, which can be provided via the Thread constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to set up a conditional breakpoint by using a condition dependent on thread-local data. Two examples:

- `Thread.currentThread().getName()`,
- some value stored in a `ThreadLocal`.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an item Filtering in the breakpoint properties dialog. There, you can limit the breakpoint to specific threads. But this only works when the program is already running since that dialog shows all threads from the running JVM.

Comment: I've tried this myself, however eclipse keeps stopping in threads that I haven't selected. It seems like conditional breakpoints are the only way to achieve this.